# Openssl RAND_bytes algorithm

Tags: random, openssl

What algorithm does the `RAND_bytes` function use in OpenSSL?

Comment: Look at the source code for yourself, it is not hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL can load and run different random-number engines, and is not limited to a single implementation.  `RAND_bytes` is implemented in `crypto/rand/rand_lib.c`, and it gets a function pointer to the concrete RNG implementation by calling the function `RAND_get_rand_method()` in the same file.

So assuming you haven't loaded a new RNG engine, OpenSSL will pick one of the following:

1. By default it chooses, `RAND_SSLeay()`, implemented in `crypto/rand/md_rand.c`, which ultimately calls `ssleay_rand_bytes()`.  I don't think it really has a name, and the randomness ultimately comes from the message digest (MD_Update).
2. If you are running the 1.0 FIPS module in FIPS mode, you get an ANSI X9.31 RNG, which uses either 3DES or AES at its core.  (Note that ANSI X9.31 is no longer allowed in FIPS 140-2).
3. If you are running the 2.0 FIPS module in FIPS mode, you get an SP 800-90A Deterministic Random Bit Generator (DRBG).

Comment: "...an ANSI X9.31 RNG. The randomness ultimately comes from 3DES." - OpenSSL 1.0.x using the FIPS Object Module 2.0, AES is now used. I'm having trouble tracking down AES128/AES/192/AES256 though (or what is used by default).

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that it changed.  OpenSSL now implements SP800-90.  It defines different key strengths so you can actually have it use AES 128, 256, or 512.  I should probably edit some info into this answer... http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf

Comment: OK, this is {intersting|embarrasing} (my bad for not checking before hand). According to the OpenSSL FIPS 2.0 User Guide, "Default DRBG," page 64: "A special DRBG instance called the "default DRBG" is used to map the DRBG to the RAND interface." Buts its [still] not clear which of the four generators from SP800-90 are used, nor the securty level of the underlying algorithm.