# randomBytes vs pseudoRandomBytes

Tags: node.js, security

In what situations is it acceptable (from a security standpoint) to use node's [`crypto.pseudoRandomBytes`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pseudorandombytes_size_callback) instead of the cryptographically-strong [`crypto.randomBytes`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)?

<s>I assume `pseudoRandomBytes` performs better at the expense of being more predictable</s> ([incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18131768/201952)), but the docs don't really have much to say about how less-strong it is.

Specifically, I'm wondering if I'm ok using `pseudoRandomBytes` to generate a CSRF token.

Comment: I don't know about how random it really is but is the performance of `crypto.randomBytes` an issue in the first place?

Comment: If you need a batch of CSRF tokens and `crypto.randomBytes` is too expensive, you could maybe do a single `crypto.randomBytes` operation and *n* `crypto.pseudoRandomBytes` operations. Then XOR each of the latter with the former and use those. I am not a crypto expert and I can't vouch for the security of such a method. It is probably better than using all `pseudoRandom` but worse than using all `crypto.random`.

Comment: We all know that database is almost always a bottleneck. Assuming that `pseudoRandomBytes` is secure I doubt you would even see the difference in performance. That's not the correct direction for optimization. Waste of time imho. Just use `randomBytes`.

Comment: I have experienced problems with crypto.randomBytes in VM environments where there is not much entropy available, it may hang much longer than db

Comment: @Plato Well, the problem doesn't exist until it exists (and it is very unlikely to happen). Also it is much easier and faster to buy a hardware random number generator, for example Ivy Bridge CPU. We are living in XXI century after all.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As it turns out, **with the default OpenSSL** (which is bundled with node, but if you've built your own, it is possible to [configure different engines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4445695/201952)), [the algorithm to generate random data](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_1e/crypto/rand/md_rand.c#L334) is exactly the same for both `randomBytes` (`RAND_bytes`) and `pseudoRandomBytes` (`RAND_pseudo_bytes`).

The one and only difference between the two calls depends on the version of node you're using:

- In node v0.12 and prior, `randomBytes` returns an error if the entropy pool has not yet been seeded with enough data.  `pseudoRandomBytes` will always return bytes, even if the entropy pool has not been properly seeded.
- In node v4 and later, `randomBytes` does not return until the entropy pool has enough data.  This should take only a few milliseconds (unless the system has just booted).

Once the the entropy pool has been seeded with enough data, it will never "run out," so there is absolutely no effective difference between `randomBytes` and `pseudoRandomBytes` *once the entropy pool is full*.

Because the exact same algorithm is used to generate randrom data, there is no difference in performance between the two calls (one-time entropy pool seeding notwithstanding).

Comment: **Source:** http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback

Comment: The docs don't mention throwing on lack of entropy; they just say that _"`randomBytes` will block until there is sufficient entropy. This should normally never take longer than a few milliseconds."_

Comment: @bfred.it: that changed in v4.  Older vesions of node [did throw when there was insufficient entropy](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback).  ("*node will throw error or invoke callback with error, if there is not enough accumulated entropy to generate cryptographically strong data. In other words, `crypto.randomBytes` without callback will not block even if all entropy sources are drained.*"  Answer updated.

Answer (score 17):

Just a clarification, both have the same performance:

```
var crypto = require ("crypto")
var speedy = require ("speedy");

speedy.run ({
    randomBytes: function (cb){
        crypto.randomBytes (256, cb);
    },
    pseudoRandomBytes: function (cb){
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes (256, cb);
    }
});

/*
File: t.js

Node v0.10.25
V8 v3.14.5.9
Speedy v0.1.1

Tests: 2
Timeout: 1000ms (1s 0ms)
Samples: 3
Total time per test: ~3000ms (3s 0ms)
Total time: ~6000ms (6s 0ms)

Higher is better (ops/sec)

randomBytes
  58,836 ± 0.4%
pseudoRandomBytes
  58,533 ± 0.8%

Elapsed time: 6318ms (6s 318ms)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like the standard PRNG implementations in other languages, it is probably either not seeded by default or it is seeded by a simple value, like a timestamp. Regardless, the seed is possibly *very* easily guessable.

Comment: The methods I'm asking about use [OpenSSL's `RAND_bytes`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_bytes.html), so I'm fairly certain that they're secure.

Comment: I was talking about the initial seed.

Comment: OpenSSL's PRNG is [seeded by OpenSSL itself](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#USER1) using `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: It's internal RNG engines will, yes, but is that always true? `RAND_bytes` will be secure, but what makes `RAND_pseudo_bytes` potentially insecure? Since they should be calling the same byte generators, I would posit that it is the seed that could be of poorer quality.

Comment: I read through OpenSSL's code and [discovered the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18131768/201952).  They use the same seed, but `RAND_bytes` will return an error if the entropy pool doesn't have enough data (whereas `RAND_pseudo_bytes` returns bytes based on the low entropy seed).  It's not that the seed is *very* weak (ie just a timestamp), it's that it's not large enough to be guaranteed secure.

Comment: I was looking through it too and noted that difference, but gave up while not yet satisfied that's all the the `ENGINE`'s `bytes` and `pseudobytes` were doing. Good job.