# Crypto.randomBytes handling exception do to inadequate entropy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

In the documentation for this method it states that it will throw an exception if there is an inadequate amount of entropy to generate the data. My question pertains to the entropy. How is it generated and can you prevent an exception from being thrown by providing adequate entropy? How common will an exception be thrown, or is it unknown?

Documentation for `crypto.randomBytes`:

> **crypto.randomBytes(size, [callback])**

```
// async
crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buf) {
  if (ex) throw ex;
  console.log('Have %d bytes of random data: %s', buf.length, buf);
});
```

> Generates cryptographically strong pseudo-random data.
>
> **Will throw error or invoke callback with error, if there is not enough
>   accumulated entropy to generate cryptographically strong data**. In
>   other words, crypto.randomBytes without callback will not block even
>   if all entropy sources are drained.

In the following example, how would I handle an exception properly and still completely fill the array, basically ensuring the array has been filled completely with the generated bytes. Would I just catch the exception and generate a new array within the catch block, but would if that also throws an exception? Essentially how would I make this code work properly 100% of the time?

```
var codes = [];
for(var i = 0;i < 100;i++){
     (function(i){
          crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buf) {
               if (ex) throw ex;
               codes[i] = buf.toString('hex');
          });
     })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no entropy is available, your best bet would be to wait a bit and try again.  How long you'd need to wait depends on how much entropy you need and how the underlying entropy sources work.

In practice, I doubt that you'll have any problems.  I don't know what Node.js does under the covers, equivalent functions in other libraries are generally implemented as calls to the OS's entropy pool - e.g. `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom()` - or as CSPRNGs that are seeded from the OS's entropy pool. In either case, you'll never block.

Blocking is only an issue if you're reading from `/dev/random` on Linux. This is because `/dev/random` may block on Linux, but doesn't on other platforms. It could also be an issue if you're reading directly from a hardware RNG.

Comment: OK, voted up, also because of the information found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130254/randombytes-vs-pseudorandombytes) but beware that the operation may differ if another engine than OpenSSL is used - especially on embedded platforms or browsers.

Comment: @owlstead I saw the answer to that question which you posted. He states that both `randomBytes` and `pseudoRandomBytes` will never 'run out' once the entropy pool is seeded with enough data. Both methods rely upon an entropy pool the only difference being is that the former throws an exception if the entropy is inadequate. Is it possible to ensure that adequate entropy always exists? Is waiting the only option if an exception is thrown? If so, how much time is sufficient for the entropy pool to fill again?

Comment: No - not if you don't know the underlying implementation. yes waiting or polling, undetermined amount of time. You may be able to add additional entropy (mouse movements) yourself. Maybe you could make sure your machine uses [RdRand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) but even then the software has to make use of it.